# What am I doing wrong with the variables?

Tags: python, variables, tkinter

I wanted to make a little program to change the capitalization of sentences to make them sound very sarcastic. I wanted to have it in a little frame and used this tutorial (https://datatofish.com/entry-box-tkinter/). I've extracted some of its code and implemented it, but I think I messed up.

The Shell constantly gives me errors about missing variable which I can't seem to find in the code. Can some of you find where I made the mistake?

```
import random
import tkinter as tk

root= tk.Tk()
root.title('hOofDleTteRdiNGes')

canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, width = 400, height = 300)
canvas1.pack()

entry1 = tk.Entry (root)
canvas1.create_window(200, 140, window=entry1)

def capi_sentence(sentence):
    sentence.lower = entry1.get()
    new_sentence = ''
    number = 0 #Dummy number for tracking

    for letter in sentence.lower():
        if len(new_sentence)<2: #Creates the first two letter
            random_number = random.randint(0,1) #This randomly decides if the letter should be upper or lowercase
            if random_number==0:
                new_sentence += letter.upper()
            else:
                new_sentence += letter
        else:
            if (new_sentence[number-2].isupper() and new_sentence[number-1].isupper() or new_sentence[number-2].islower() and new_sentence[number-1].islower())==True:
                #Checks if the two letters before are both upper or lowercase
                if new_sentence[number-1].isupper(): #Makes the next letter the opposite of the letter before
                    new_sentence += letter.lower()
                else:
                    new_sentence += letter.upper()
            else:
                random_number = random.randint(0,1)
                if random_number==0:
                    new_sentence += letter.upper()
                else:
                    new_sentence += letter
                
        number += 1 #Add one more to the tracking
     
    label1 = tk.label(new_sentence)

button1 = tk.Button(text='hoofdletter shufflen', command=capi_sentence)
canvas1.create_window(200, 180, window=button1)
```

Comment: Please, add error message :)

Comment: Oh, I totally forgot that. I will remind me to do this is in the future :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few problems.

1. You need to call `root.mainloop()` at the end so a window will appear.
2. Your `capi_sentence` function takes an argument but the callback called when pressing the button does not give it one.

Use

```
button1 = tk.Button(text='hoofdletter shufflen', command=lambda: capi_sentence(entry1.get()))
```

which calls your function with the return value of `entry1.get()`.

3. The first line of capi_sentence is unnecessary (and doesn't really make sense anyway) after you properly pass in the text.
4. You've used lowercase `label` when creating the label. You also need to pass in a parent widget (e.g. root) and pass in the text as the `text` keyword argument. Finally, you need to add it to the window by packing it.

```
    label1 = tk.Label(root, text=new_sentence)
    label1.pack()
```

Some misc tips:

You do not need `== True` at the end of your conditional; if will already run if true.

You can remove the explicit `number` logic by using `enumerate`, which returns a list of tuples (i, item), with item the original item in the list and i its index from 0 to N - 1.
I've rewritten your for loop below with this (and other simplifications) so it's a bit easier to read.

```
for i, letter in enumerate(sentence.lower()):
  maybe_upper = letter.upper() if random.randint(0, 1) else letter
  if len(new_sentence) < 2: #Creates the first two letter
    new_sentence += maybe_upper
  else:
    l2, l1 = new_sentence[i - 2 : i]
    if (l1.isupper() and l2.isupper()) or (l1.islower() and l2.islower()):
      #Checks if the two letters before are both upper or lowercase
      new_sentence += letter.lower() if l1.isupper() else letter.upper()
    else:
      new_sentence += maybe_upper
```